# Crash when trying to use LibGDX and OpenGL ES 2.0 on Android

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, libgdx

I have a problem with my snake game for android. I have managed to write a simple application with LibGDX and it works. However when I try to use OpenGL ES 2.0 (as opposed to 1.0) it crashes on both an Android phone and a virtual device. It works fine on desktop.

I know that my phone supports OpenGL ES 2.0 as the sample application from this [tutorial](http://developer.android.com/training/graphics/opengl/index.html) works just fine.

The problem occurs when I change the line:

```
cfg.useGL20 = false;
```

to

```
cfg.useGL20 = true;
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: please post stacktrace and relevant code

Comment: did you update libgdx within the past two weeks or so?

Comment: well I downloaded it just recently so I have the latest version (release not nightly), also I've tried using the debug tool and the program seems to crash when it tries to acces GLSurfaceView, and it promts me to attach a source file containing that class.

Comment: GL20 is not supported by emulator, may be problem is with your libraries. If you're using jars did you checked all jars in Order&Export in java build path